Why does the "Footprint" memory size not equal the "phys_footprint" in the Auxiliary data reported by the Footprint cmd
I am using the footprint command to analyze a memgraph file exported from Xcode, and I have noticed that the Footprint and phys_footprint values in the analysis results are not the same.Why?Thanks.enter image description here
I tried to find a correlation between this analysis result and the results from the heap command, but I was not successful.enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
